# Kotlin - Don't run unit test until lateinit property is initialized

Tags: kotlin, junit, race-condition

I have a case where the unit of code I'm testing is running on a different thread and so the test executes and fails before the unit has finished executing:

```kotlin
class Tests {
    private lateinit var result: String

    @BeforeAll
    fun setup() {
        DataService().subscribe {
            result = it
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun `get result from data service`() {
        assert(result.contains("Hello"))
    }
}
```

When the test runs, I get the following exception:

> kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property result has not been initialized

How can I ensure that the tests don't run before `result` has been initialized?

Comment: Is there a way for you to get the data synchronously from `DataService()`? Because clearly here the setup method returns before the body of `subscribe` is called.

Answer (score 0):

The test in the provided form won't work: `@BeforeAll` is allowed only on static methods, but then it couldn't access the `result` field. It can be solved by using `@BeforeEach` and `@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_METHOD)` [but see the **UPDATE** at the end of the post]

Regarding the `result` initialization itself: you can check if it has been initialized using `this::result.isInitialized`, e.g.:

```kotlin
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_METHOD)
class AwaitTest {

    private lateinit var result: String

    @BeforeEach
    fun setup() {
        DataService().subscribe {
            result = it
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun `get result from data service`() = runBlocking {
        awaitInitialization()
        assert(result.contains("Hello"))
    }

    suspend fun awaitInitialization() {
        while(!this::result.isInitialized) {
            delay(100)
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could use [awaitility](https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility):

```kotlin
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_METHOD)
class AwaitTest {

    private lateinit var result: String

    @BeforeEach
    fun setup() {
        DataService().subscribe {
            result = it
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun `get result from data service`() {
        await until { this@AwaitTest::result.isInitialized }
        assert(result.contains("Hello"))
    }

}
```

Or even better, move `await` to the `setup()` method:

```kotlin
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_METHOD)
class AwaitTest {

    private lateinit var result: String

    @BeforeEach
    fun setup() {
        DataService().subscribe {
            result = it
        }
        await until { this@AwaitTest::result.isInitialized }
    }

    @Test
    fun `get result from data service`() {
        assert(result.contains("Hello"))
    }

}
```

**UPDATE**:

Actually a `@BeforeAll` method doesn't need to be static if the test class is annotated with the`@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)`:

```kotlin
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class AwaitTest {

    private lateinit var result: String

    @BeforeAll
    fun setup() {
        DataService().subscribe {
            result = it
        }
        await until { this@AwaitTest::result.isInitialized }
    }

    @Test
    fun `get result from data service`() {
        assert(result.contains("Hello"))
    }

}
```

Comment: All good suggestions...except I should have mentioned, I'm also limited to Kotlin 1.2, so no await :-(

Comment: It's not Kotlin's await, it's from Awaitility's kotlin DSL